# How can I copy a file from a CD when Finder reports error code -36?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, error, copy-paste

I have a CD. I copied the whole CD to another location - except for one file. When trying to copy that particular file, I get following error:

> The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in
>   "filename.extension" can't be read or written. (Error code -36)

This file is neither particularly large nor any unusual file type, and I do have the permission to read that file (it's on a read-only CD).

What can be done about that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the physical cd scratched?

Answer (score 2):

## Error code -36

-36 (ioErr) (I/O error) is a file system error, it indicates that data cannot be sent or received by the operating system. Historically, [errors of this type were bummers](http://web.archive.org/web/20100827221247/http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1618).

## Finder: source and destination

Think not only of the source (the CD); think also of the destination.

### The file

What is the one file that Finder can not copy?

### The file system

What type of file system is the destination? The answer will be amongst results to the following command:

`mount`

A volume with file system type `hfs` should be good for most purposes.

Depending on what you wish to copy, other types of file system may be equally good.

## Disk Utility

For copying a CD in its entirety – or for imaging a file system within a CD – Disk Utility is ideal.