# Error -36 while copying .pkg from ftp server

Tags: finder, ftp

I obtain an error

> Some data can't be read or written (error code -36)

while copying a `.pkg` file from an ftp server in Finder. I have read this [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40334/how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-a-cd-when-finder-reports-error-code-36). I have contacted the owner of the ftp server about this issue. Is there anything I can do myself?

Comment: You may want to try a dedicated FTP application, they tend to do a better job (in my experience) than using Finder for FTP copy. Also if you are comfortable in the command line you can do FTP there as well.

Comment: Use Disk Utility to wrap the .pkg file in a disk image. IIRC, a .pgk file is just a folder structure (invisible to the user). Use File > New Image > Image from Folder ... and create the .dmg, which is a monolithic file. Transfer the .dmg, then unpack on the other end.

Comment: @SteveChambers Indeed, I was able to copy it using `FileZilla`. I invite you to repeat your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try a dedicated FTP application, they tend to do a better job (in my experience) than using Finder for FTP copy. Also if you are comfortable in the command line you can do FTP there as well.